# File IO for MPI-FORTRAN

Tags: file-io, fortran, mpi

I have a FORTRAN MPI code to solve a flow field.

At the start I want to read data from file and distribute it to the participating processes.

The data is consisting of several 3-D arrays(velocities in space x,y,z).

Every process stores only a part of the array.

So if every process is going to read the file(the easiest way I think) it is not going to work as it will only store a the first part of the file corresponding to the number of arrays that the process can hold.

MPI Bcast can work for 3d arrays? But then things become complex.

Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4):

You have, broadly speaking, 2 or 3 choices, depending on your platform.

1. One process reads the input data and sends (parts of) it to the other processes. I wouldn't usually use broadcast for this since it is a collective operation and all processes have to take part.  I'd usually just send the necessary information to each process.  If it is convenient (and not a memory issue) you could certainly broadcast all the input data to all the processes, it's just not a pattern of operation that I use or see much.
2. All processes read the data that they require.  This may involve a process reading an entire input file and only storing those parts it requires.  But if you have very large input files you can write routines to read only the necessary part into each process's memory space.  This approach may involve processes competing for disk access, which is only slow in a relative sense: if you are running large-scale and long-running parallel computations waiting a few seconds while all the processes get their data is not much of an overhead.
3. If you have a parallel file system then you can use MPI's parallel I/O routines so that each process reads only those parts of the input data that it requires.

Comment: Is there any example for the second option I could look at?

Answer (score 3):

The canonical way of such an I/O pattern in MPI is either to

- Read the data on rank 0, then use MPI_Scatter to distribute it. Or if memory is tight, do this blockwise, or then use 1-to-1 communication rather than MPI_Scatter.
- Use MPI-I/O, and have each rank read its own subset of the data file (to be useful, this of course requires a file format where you can figure out the boundaries without first reading through the entire file).

For extreme scalability, one can combine the two approaches, that is a subset of processes (say, sqrt(N) as a rough rule of thumb) use MPI I/O, and each MPI process sends data to its own IO process.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running your code on less than 1000 cores with a good file system (e.g. Lustre) then just use Fortran I/O where each rank opens the file and reads the data it needs (skipping the rest). Yes it takes a few minutes but you're only reading the file once during start.

MPI I/O (binary only) is non-trivial and usually you are always better off using higher level libs such as HDF5 or Parallel NetCDF. Performance will depend on how the data is read (contiguous vs non-contiguous and so on). The following links may be helpful ...

- http://www.osc.edu/supercomputing/training/pario/parallel-io-nov04.pdf
- https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/images/0/01/Parallel_io_course.pdf

Comment: Thanks for suggesting HDF5 or Parallel-NetCDF: today there is rarely a reason to have new code use MPI-IO directly.